# Keeping numbers the same length

Tags: go

I'm completing an example involving a clock, so I'm working with integers between 0 and 60 in some cases, and 0 and 12 in others. I need the length of each number to be two digits long, even when the value is less than 10.

For example

```
0  => 00
2  => 02
10 => 10
etc
```

I want to have them formatted, but not necessarily to print them out. What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
fmt.Printf("%02d", number)
```

Have a look at `fmt`'s [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) to understand how it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to format the number without printing it out?

Comment: A number is just a *value*, it doesn't have *length* until you create a *string representation* of that value. If you just want a string without printing it, you can do `strval := fmt.Sprintf("%02d", number)` instead.